# Проверка создания файла в Java

Tags: java, файлы

Делаю простую консольную программу, которая при запуске просит указать путь для создания нового файла на HDD пользователя. Файл может быть только .txt , столкнулся с проблемой, что пользователь может ввести некорректный путь который не может существовать, или некорректное имя файла. Или, еще случай, если ввести просто символ "A", то программа создаст файл "A" без расширения в директории моего проекта. Как сделать корректную проверку, создался ли файл на диске? Пробовал с *file.exists()* и *file.isFile()*, но тогда в последнем случае проверка получается пройденной.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Введите путь к файлу");
    String filePath = reader.readLine();
    File file = new File(filePath);
    file.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверить расширение можно до создания файла. Простой вариант - использовать `filePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")`. Такой вариант не учитывает попытки вроде `name..txt`. Сложный вариант проверки - тема для отдельного вопроса.

Сама проверка создания файла не требуется. Метод `createNewFile()` сгенерирует исключение, если что-то пойдет не так. Вам достаточно будет его поймать и корректно обработать.

Если пользователь вводит просто имя, то появление файла в каком-то месте по умолчанию - ожидаемо. Если Вы хотите, чтобы каталог обязательно был указан, я бы разделил процесс на два пункта:

1. Просим ввести путь к файлу без самого имени. Мы можем проверить является ли путь каталогом при помощи метода [`isDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory())
2. Просим ввести имя файла, проверяем расширение, и создаем объект файла конструктором [`File(String parent, String child)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))